# Database result for some reason prints only "[]"

Tags: python, sql, database, tkinter

I wanted to essentially debug my program and see what info I am getting:

```
def Loginukas():
    ## Login interface
    username = str(user_entry.get())
    passvordiukas = str(pass_entry.get())
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM "Login_Info" WHERE "Username" = ? AND "Password" = ?', (username, passvordiukas))
    result = cur.fetchall()
    print(username)
    print(passvordiukas)
    print(result)
```

The thing is when I print it I get the proper entries but my database seems to only show [] which I assume it means it does not detect any specific fields. Not sure why It does this but it seems that the connection to my sql database is there and all the fields and tables are right. So I am quite confused.

I tried changing the names of my database and rephrasing the code but it did not really work.

Comment: Remove quotation marks " from the query string, so it should be `SELECT * FROM Login_info WHERE ...`

Comment: When I construct a program with a database and I call this function, it works as  expected - it finds the correct row in the database. Please create a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem. For the purposes of this question you can hard-code a little in-memory database.

Comment: @nacho: removing the quotes won't change the result.

Comment: If you remove the WHERE clause, does it still return no results? eg: `'SELECT * FROM Login_Info'`

Answer (score 0):

```
def Loginukas():
    ## Login interface
    username = str(user_entry.get())
    passvordiukas = str(pass_entry.get())
    params = {"username": username, "passowrd": passvordiukas}
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM "Login_Info" WHERE "Username" = :username AND "Password" = :password', params)
    result = cur.fetchall()
    print(username)
    print(passvordiukas)
    print(result)
```

The best way to pass parameters in a query is with dictionary because it's the most secure way to do it:

```
params = {"username": username, "passowrd": passvordiukas}
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM "Login_Info" WHERE "Username" = :username AND "Password" = :password', params)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).